# Specifying the location of AndroidManifest.xml in a Java project compiled with sbt android-plugin

Tags: android, scala, build, android-manifest, sbt

I'm trying to use sbt to compile an Android Project made in Java, which I just inherited and want to improve with Scala.

The project is splited across several modules. I've created an sbt project with "`g8 jberkel/android-app -b sbt-0_11`", copied all the modules to src/ leaving me with:

```
my-android-project  ls -l src 
total 96
drwxr-xr-x  14 tiagoboldt  staff    476 Oct 18 16:09 AndroidApplication
drwxr-xr-x   8 tiagoboldt  staff    272 Oct 18 16:09 CRCCalculatioNTool
drwxr-xr-x  10 tiagoboldt  staff    340 Oct 18 16:09 CaretakerIntegration
drwxr-xr-x  13 tiagoboldt  staff    442 Oct 18 16:09 ConsoleSensorNetwork
... and so on
```

These modules have dependencies between them, AndroidApplication is the main application I want to build. I've been trying to edit my project/build.scala, which I've altered from the original to include the following :

```
object AndroidBuild extends Build {
  lazy val AndroidApplication = Project (
    "AndroidApplication",
    file("."),
    settings = General.fullAndroidSettings ++ PlainJavaProject.settings
  ) 
}
```

While trying to build, I always end up with:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: (rest_of_dir)/my-android-project/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)
```

I can't understand how to configure it to have it look for that file in src/AndroidApplication/src/AndroidManifest.xml, instead of the default one. Already tried to play with the file value and no go :\

The documentation of both sbt and it's android plugin didn't help. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with libgdx, I just used this:

```
lazy val android = 
  Settings.common ++
  AndroidProject.androidSettings ++
  TypedResources.settings ++
  proguardSettings ++
  AndroidManifestGenerator.settings ++
  AndroidMarketPublish.settings ++
  Seq (
    platformName in Android := "android-7",
    keyalias in Android := "change-me",
    mainAssetsPath in Android := file("common/src/main/resources"),
    manifestPath in Android := Seq(file("android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml"))
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps:

```
object AndroidBuild extends Build {
  val AndroidApplication = Project (
  "AndroidApplication",
  file("AndroidApplication"),
   settings = General.fullAndroidSettings ++ PlainJavaProject.settings
  ) dependsOn xxxxx 

  lazy val CRCCalculatioNTool = Project (
  "CRCCalculatioNTool",
  file("CRCCalculatioNTool"),
  settings = General.fullAndroidSettings ++ PlainJavaProject.settings
  ) dependsOn yyy

  lazy val CaretakerIntegration = Project (
  "CaretakerIntegration",
  file("CaretakerIntegration"),
   settings = General.fullAndroidSettings ++ PlainJavaProject.settings
  ) dependsOn zzz
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in case you are trying to configure the plugin to change the default paths then i think you also need to configure the setting `manifestTemplatePath`:

```
settings = General.fullAndroidSettings ++ inConfig(Android)(Seq(
  manifestPath <<= (baseDirectory, manifestName in Android) (_ / _),
  manifestTemplatePath <<= (manifestPath in Android) (mp => mp),
  mainAssetsPath <<= baseDirectory (_ / "assets"),
  mainResPath <<= baseDirectory (_ / "res")
))
```

Remove `manifestTemplatePath` and you'll get the error you're seeing.